# CakePHP submitting a form to right action

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this in add.ctp:

```
<!-- File: /app/views/posts/add.ctp --> 

<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
echo $form->create('Post');
echo $form->input('title');
echo $form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

and this in my controller:

```
function add(){
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if($this->Post->save($this->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how does CakePHP know that when the user hits submit, to send "data" to the function "add" in the controller?

Comment: Why did you not allow my PHP tag? I have PHP on ignore.

Comment: I havent disallowed anything :)

Comment: This is a readability issue I have when first learning CakePHP. It's not very clear how the view layer is connected to the control and model layers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default CakePHP will send the form to the same action that displayed it.

You can change it in the view as follows:

```
echo $form->create('Post', array('action' => 'whatever'));
```

Comment: this warning is for latest cake, replace action with url. Follow the answer of @dav

Answer (score 9):

or if you want to redirect to another controller as well you can use this

`echo $form->create('Post', array('url' => '/controller_name/action_name'));`

Answer (score 0):

As per the updated syntax below will work `(CakePHP 2.4.x)`:

```
echo $this->Form->create('RegistrationsInout', array('action' => 'startroom'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For cakephp 3.x

```
$this->Form->create('Post', ['url' => ['action' => 'post']]);
```

See [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#setting-a-url-for-the-form)